# Maven SLF4J error

Tags: maven, binding, slf4j

During the building of my project, I get the following warning notification

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:(...)/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:(...)/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Normally, the error is thrown when you  include multiple slf4j libraries, which causes the manifest to have multiple entries of the logging lib. But as you can see here, the "multiple binding" happens on the exact same library and the exact same class.

I figured that I should have some dependencies that refer to the same library, and that I should include one of them. But this is the `dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.5.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.0.0.ga:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:provided
[INFO] +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
```

Which also doesn't seem to include multiple libraries of slf4j.

My question, does anyone know where this warning comes from? 
(I am totally aware that it is *just*  a warning, but for customer sake I'd like to have no warnings when delivering a product)

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Running from command line or within Jenkins/ IDE ?

Comment: Hey! I'm running Maven 3.2.3 from the commandline.

Comment: Can you add the full output of a run `mvn clean packge | tee mvn.log`?

Comment: The error will not be shown in that log. It only shows when I run the program.

Comment: At start...before the build runs...running during the tests or where?

Comment: After building the package, I kick off the Main class, this is when the warning is printed.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a manifestation of an [SLF4J bug](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-129) that was marked as resolved back in August of 2011, around the time this question was posed.  Version 1.6.1 of slf4j was released prior to the fix, but it looks like updating to any version more recent than 1.6.3 should have the fix.